# Find an element value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following HTML markup, how can I get the value of the input field which has the name `module_id[]`, by clicking on the span class `.click`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="module">
    <div class="info">..</div>
    <div class="ctrl"><span class="click">Click</span></div>
    <input type="hidden" value="module1" name="module_id[]" /> 
    <input type="hidden" value="title" name="module_title[]" />
</div>
```

I have tried this:

**jQuery:**

```
$('.module').on('click','.click',function(){
     var target_module = $(this).parent();
     var module_id = target_module.find('input[name=module_id\\[\\]]').val();

    alert(module_id);

 });
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/FKdNJ/

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_first.asp `$("input:first")` shall work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
$('input[name="module_id[]"').val();
```

**[jsFiddle example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FKdNJ/2/)**

```
$('.module').on('click', '.click', function () {
    console.log($('input[name="module_id[]"').val());
});
```

If you have more than one set of this block of code, use `$(this).closest('.ctrl').next().val()`:

as in:

```
$('.module').on('click', '.click', function () {
    console.log($(this).closest('.ctrl').next().val());
});
```

**[jsFiddle example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FKdNJ/9/)**

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).parent();` is giving you the `<div class="ctrl">` instead.

You could use `$(this).parent().parent()`, but a more flexible solution is to use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) instead;

```
$(this).closest('.module');
```

You can see this working here; http://jsfiddle.net/FKdNJ/5/

---

FWIW, you could also change your approach completely, and use [`e.delegateTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/) to retrieve the `.module` element directly (http://jsfiddle.net/FKdNJ/7/);

```
$('.module').on('click','.click',function(e){
     var target_module = $(e.delegateTarget);
     var module_id = target_module.find('input[name=module_id\\[\\]]').val();

     alert(module_id);
});
```

Comment: Good to know that there is such a property in the jqEvent for delegate binding

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.module').on('click','.click',function(){
    alert($(this).closest('.module').find('[name="module_id[]"]:first').val())
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FKdNJ/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FKdNJ/10/).  You're probably better off using html 5 data- attributes if possible.

```
$('span.click').click(function(){     
    var moduleId = $(this).closest("div.module").find("input[name='module_id[]']").val()
    alert(moduleId);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a answer in fiddle:

```
$('.click').on('click',function(){
     alert($('input[name=module_id\\[\\]]').val());
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FKdNJ/6/